# How to enter text into popup window with JavaScript (or PowerShell)?

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script that accesses a website in order to upload an image

When it presses a button, it throws up windows explorer to select a file. I want my script to enter a preselected url into the text field, however this windows explorer screen is not part of the actual document. This means I cannot access as I would a textbox or textarea.

I have the aim of translating this script into JavaScript (since PowerShell and JavaScript use almost identical code for accessing webpages), so a way to do this in (ideally native) JS would also be appreciated.

The webpage in question is: http://imageupper.com/cgi/uploads.pl

I am clicking on the first "Browse" button, which is `document.getElementById('fileo1').click()`, but I don't know how to enter data into the subsequent file explorer popup.

Comment: Since choosing a file means interacting with the user's file system, JavaScript has no way of manipulating the popup. I'm not sure about PowerShell.

Comment: @Sidney even if it's just to write a string?

Comment: Even just a string. I'm not aware of any way for JavaScript to programmatically select a file, because JavaScript is sandboxed completely from the user's file system. The only way to "give" JavaScript a file is using the native file picker, which is under the user's control.

Comment: @Sidney hmm okay, well thank you for your help

Comment: I have done this sort of work for web sites that offer no API. I used tools like autoit and ahk. However I have learned over the years that powershell can do just as much but there is very little appetite for anyone to want to use powershell this way. There is a lot of .net code you would need to write and you wouldn't do so with powershell, you would use VB, c# etc. I have also learned that python is also a great tool for this specific use case as there is a very large community whom have created packages and or extensible libraries.

Comment: @AlbertoVargas ahh okay, I hadn’t really considered using Python (I’m somewhat used to writing .NET code within Powershell). I’ll take a look at it then. Any specific libraries to get started with?